# Visio shape - get X,Y position

Tags: c#, visio

I've managed to programatically insert a shape into Visio using the code below:

```
ActiveWindow.Page.Drop(VisioApp.Documents["ORGCH_M.VSS"].Masters.ItemU["Executive"], 5.433071, 7.559055);
```

How would i programatically retrieve it's X,Y coordinates after the shape has been inserted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the coordinates of the new shape first get a reference to the new shape. [Page.Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224597%28v=office.11%29.aspx) will retun this reference. Then look in that shape object for its [PinX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221220%28office.11%29.aspx) and [PinY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221225%28v=office.11%29.aspx) cells. This will give you the coordinates in Visio's default units i.e. inches. Here is an example in VBA:

```
Dim newShape As Visio.Shape
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double

Set newShape = ActiveWindow.Page.Drop(Visio.Application.Documents("ORGCH_M.VSS")
                    .Masters.ItemU("Executive"), 5.433071, 7.559055)

x = newShape.Cells("PinX")
y = newShape.Cells("PinY")
```

I notice you are working in a metric drawing (i.e. _M in the filename). You may prefer to work in a different unit. Here is the same example using millimeters:

```
Dim newShape As Visio.Shape
Dim xIn As Double
Dim yIn As Double
Dim xOut As Double
Dim yOut As Double

xIn = Visio.Application.ConvertResult(100, visMillimeters, visInches)
yIn = Visio.Application.ConvertResult(120, visMillimeters, visInches)

Set newShape = ActiveWindow.Page.Drop(Visio.Application.Documents("ORGCH_M.VSS")
                    .Masters.ItemU("Executive"), xIn, yIn)

xOut = newShape.Cells("PinX").Result(visMillimeters)
yOut = newShape.Cells("PinY").Result(visMillimeters)
```